# Using global variable within WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Within my header.php file, I need to set the body ID dynamically depending on the currently used template for whatever page someone happens to be viewing.

If someone is viewing a page that uses template A the body tag should look like this:

```
<body id="page1">
```

If someone is viewing a page that uses template B the body tag should look like this:

```
<body id="page2">
```

What would be the downside to me setting the following variable within my themes functions.php

```
$GLOBALS['my_current_body_id'];
```

Then at the beginning of each template I set the following:

```
$GLOBALS['my_current_body_id'] = '1';
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['my_current_body_id'] = '2';
```

and so on depending on how I need to style and structure the particular page.

Then in my header.php file I do the following:

```
<body id="page<?php echo $GLOBALS['my_current_body_id']?>">
```

I am wondering if there is a problem with using this type of approach that I might be overlooking.

For example, if two people hit the site at the exact same time, could there be a mix up or is the $GLOBALS['my_current_body_id'] specific to the user viewing the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

PHP:

```
function body_tag() {
    global $post;
    $pageid = $post->ID; // Get page ID
    switch($pageid) {
        case '1':
        $bodyid = '1';
        break;

        case '2':
        $bodyid = '2';
        break;

        case '3':
        $bodyid = '3';
        break;

        default:
        $bodyid = '';
    }
    // Based on the page ID, set the appropriate bodyid and then return it.

    return $bodyid;
}
```

Header.php:

```
<body id="page<?php echo body_tag(); ?>">
```

The code I wrote feels a bit more simple, however...
If user A and user B are viewing the same page, they will see the same template. 
But if user A is viewing the page with ID 4 and user B is viewing the page with ID 5, then they will see different templates.
Are you trying to make a plugin for A/B testing?

Comment: Interesting, however switching off the page ID would be problematic because I have over 100 pages. I thought about switching off the the template ID but then each time I created a new template, I would need to update that function. This is why I wanted to somehow set a parameter or variable within the template itself.

Comment: Are you trying to make a plugin for A/B testing? If so, you might want to go differently about it. why not make a table in SQL and call it visits. And then log every visit as: IP, TemplateShown. And whenever someone is landing on the page, you have a function that checks how many times has each template been shown. If template A has been shown 300 times, but template B only 299, then show template B, i.e. add the template tag for template B.

Comment: No, this is not for a plugin. What I've listed above is on my site and it's working. I am just wondering if this is not a good idea to use a global variable like I am.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well as long as the performance is not suffering, I don't see why it would be bad to use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple methods, depending on what's needed:

1) To grab the 'post_name' of the direct parent to the Page:

```
<?php
$page = $wp_query->post;
$parent_name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '$page->post_parent;'");
?>
```

And to display the parent Page's name:

```
<body id="<?php echo $parent_name; ?>">
```

2) To collect it for the *top* parent, that is the one at the top of a Page parent<>child heirarchy, we can modify the code from jpepper's link:

```
<?php
$current_page = $post->ID;
$parent = 1;

while($parent) {
$page_query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name, post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '$current_page'");
$parent = $current_page = $page_query->post_parent;
if(!$parent)
$parent_name = $page_query->post_name;
}
?>
```

Then use the same method as above to display the name.
For better way you can simply use it a function in functions.php and use it in header.php file.

Source : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dynamic-id-for-ltbodygt-and-subpages